# Sorting a huge text file and doing a binary search

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Assume a huge file with a text information -

Contents

```
"Hello, How are you?
This is Bob
The contents of the file needs to be searched
and I'm a very huge file"
```

Search String

```
 Bob
```

Now I need to search for word "Bob" in the file and do a binary search..How can I do this?

I tried to sort the file using UNIX SORT and I got the following output -

```
and I'm a very huge file
How are you?
The contents of the file needs to be searched
This is Bob
```

It sorts the file but the word "Bob" is in the last line.

The problem with this is search is "Im not searching a whole line" instead a single word within a file..

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Split the file into words?

Comment: So let me get this straight. You want to preprocess a file, so that you can subsequently do multiple word queries fast? What is the result of a query? Yes/No for match or no match or some kind of meta information as well?

Comment: Yes/No would be the result..

Comment: The answer to your question is one word: "Index".  This seems like it might be homework, so I'll leave you with: "Create an index from keywords to line numbers and store it in a separate file."

Comment: Can we presume you'll be doing more than one search against this sorted file? Otherwise it's more efficient to just do a linear search through the file rather than sorting it.

Comment: How large is the file? How many words are in the file? Wil it fit into memory? How many queries do you plan to do on that one version of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this would be to create a generator, which yields individual words and then compare them against the word you are looking for.

```
def get_next_word():
    with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            for word in line.strip().split():
                yield word

print any(word == "Bob" for word in get_next_word())
# True
```

We use `any` function, which short circuits when it finds a match. So, we don't have to process the entire file.

**Edit:**

If you are going to be searching more than once, the best way would be to convert the list of words to a set and then use the `in` operator to check if the word exist or not.

```
words_set = set(get_next_word())

print "Bob" in words_set
# True
print "the" in words_set
# True
print "thefourtheye" in words_set
# False
```

Comment: But if you can preprocess the file and have multiple queries, this is an *n* factor or so away from optimal

Comment: @NiklasB. That sounds like a different problem statement to me :)

Comment: OP obviously *tried* to do preprocessing (GNU sort) and fast queries (binary search) but failed. So this sounds pretty plausible to me

Comment: @NiklasB. As far as I understand, all he knows is that binary search is the fastest searching algorithm. For that to work, the data has to be sorted. So, he tried unix sort and then he realized that it sorts the lines, not the words.

Comment: That is one possible interpretation, yes

Comment: @NiklasB. So, we are offering him the simplest and straight forward solution. If he likes to preprocess the information, creating a set should solve his problem.

Comment: I have to admit your interpretation didn't occur to me at all. In any case, the question needs to be clarified

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, its kind of open ended. Anyway, I suggested the set based approach as well, please check. :)